# how to read orc transaction hive table in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, orc

How to read orc transaction hive table in spark?

I am facing issue while reading ORC transactional table through  spark  I get schema of hive table but not able to read actual data

*See complete scenario :*

```
hive> create table default.Hello(id int,name string) clustered by
(id) into 2 buckets STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES
('transactional'='true');
   
hive> insert into default.hello values(10,'abc');
```

Now I am trying to access Hive Orc data from Spark sql but it show
only schema

```
>spark.sql("select * from  hello").show()
```

Output: id,name

Answer (score 2):

Yes as a workaround we can use compaction, but when the job is micro batch compaction won't help. so I decided to use a JDBC call. Please refer my answer for this issue in the below link or refer my GIT page - https://github.com/Gowthamsb12/Spark/blob/master/Spark_ACID

[Please refer my answer for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199369/how-to-access-the-hive-acid-table-in-spark-sql/56233085#56233085)

Answer (score 1):

spark is not right now (2.3 version) fully compliant with hive transactional tables. The workaround is to make a compaction on the table after any transaction.

> ALTER TABLE Hello COMPACT 'major';

This compaction should make you able to see the data. (after some time the data is compacted)

Answer (score -1):

You would need to add an action at the end to force it to run the query:

```
spark.sql("Select * From Hello").show()
```

(The default here is to show 20 rows)

or

```
spark.sql("Select * From Hello").take(2)
```

to see 2 rows of output data.

These are just examples of actions that can be taken on a DataFrame.

Comment: The question is about reading orc transactional tables from spark, the statement already has show() in it.

Comment: Looking at the last edit timestamp, I believe the original didn't.